# Why does pip freeze not generate dependencies?

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, pip

New to Python(v3.9) and its `pip` utility. **Not** using any type of virtual environment (this is a Mac OS laptop I'm on). I previously generated a [deployment package](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html) via:

```
python3 -m pip install --target ./package -r requirements.txt
```

I added a few source files that pulled in a few other libraries and now I'm trying to update my `requirements.txt` file to include those libs in future deployment packages. My *understanding* of how to do this is via (ran from the project root):

```
python3 -m pip freeze
```

But I wanted to make sure `pip` would actually pull in the new dependencies I recently added, so instead of modifying `requirements.txt` I chose to try using `pip freeze` on a test/temp file, just to see what happens:

```
python3 -m pip freeze -r piptest.txt
## The following requirements were added by pip freeze:
```

First off it wouldn't even let me run this without first creating a blank/empty `piptest.txt` file. But once I did, it ran with the output above, and `piptest.txt` is still empty.

**Am I misunderstanding how `pip freeze` is intended on being used?** My *understanding* is that you use `pip freeze` to generate a requirements file, and then you can *use* that requirements file, subsequently, to do any number of other things, including (my case) generating a deployment package with it. So if my understanding is misled, please correct me! And if its not, then why is `piptest.txt` still empty after I run it?

Answer (score 0):

`pip freeze > requirements.txt`

Comment: thanks but same result (`pip freeze > piptest.txt`)

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup yes, but by convention such a file should be called requirements

Comment: ok, so when I run `pip freeze > requirements.txt` now the requirements.txt file (which was previously a valid requirements file, full of dependency info) is blank...

Comment: I don't know what are you trying to get. `pip freeze` returns a list of dependencies in the environment. `pip freeze > requirements.txt` saves this list to a file. consider using git and venv, then you won't have such problems. there's a possibility to run lambda using a virtual environment

Comment: Super simple use case. I have a Python3 project that uses a lot of different 3rd party libraries. I want to run `pip freeze` so that it generates a `requirements.txt` file that lists all of those dependencies in it. Currently there is already a `requirements.txt` file but it is old/out-of-date. So I want to update it. But when I run `pip freeze > requirements.txt` it overwrites the (existing + valid) `requirements.txt` file with an empty file. I'm wondering why?

Comment: first of all, install all the dependencies from the outdated file using `pip install -r requirements.txt`, then install all the libraries that you expect to be in your file using `pip install *library name*`, check if there're all libraries that you need using `pip freeze` and the end use `pip freeze > requirements.txt`